# waypoints, offset value from the data attribute

Tags: jquery, offset, jquery-waypoints

I am struggling the get the value from my HTML element's data attributes. For each element, i want to use different offset so i planned to get the offset value from the data attribute.

here is my code

```
<div class="waypoint" data-waypoint-offset="50%" >
// my code
</div>
```

And this my script

```
$('.waypoint').waypoint(function() {
    $(this.element).addClass('animated');
}, {
    triggerOnce: true,
    offset: function() {
       return $(this.element).data('waypoint-offset');
   }
})
```

But class "animated" added only after element reaches the top(offset 0).

I also tried

```
return $(this).data('waypoint-offset');
```

But doesn't help.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix by the author of the plugin,

```
$('.waypoint').each(function() {
    var $element = $(this);

    $element.waypoint(function() {
        $element.addClass('animated');
        this.destroy();
    }, {
        offset: $element.data('waypoint-offset')
    });
});
```

Above answer also can be found at github thread, https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/452 Thanks to [imakewebthings](https://github.com/imakewebthings)